# MySQL: can't create user The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a new user using:

```
CREATE USER 'mynewuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

However I get

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Is there any other way to create the new user? I'm currently not able to run the MySQL without the `skip-grant-tables` option...

Comment: Try running `flush privileges;` first. Then `CREATE USER 'mynewuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` and `flush privileges;` again. Does it help ?